# null at Database helper , ORMLite and fragments

Tags: android, database, ormlite

got problem with ORMLite and database helper. I've read that because of using fragments I need to create new class - OrmLiteFragment which extends Fragment. I did it, but I'm getting null at line :

```
databaseHelper =
                    OpenHelperManager.getHelper(getActivity(), DatabaseHelper.class);
```

Here's my class :

```
public class OrmLiteFragment extends Fragment {

private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = null;


protected DatabaseHelper getHelper() {
    if (databaseHelper == null) {
        databaseHelper =
                OpenHelperManager.getHelper(getActivity(), DatabaseHelper.class);
    }
    return databaseHelper;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (databaseHelper != null) {
        OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();
        databaseHelper = null;
    }

}
```

And, here's my DatabasebaseHelper. class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "link.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private RuntimeExceptionDao<Link, Integer> linkRuntimeDao = null;
private Dao<Link, Integer> linkDao;


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, R.raw.ormlite_config);

}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    Log.d("onCreate", "Creating Database");
    try {
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Link.class);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Unable to create database", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public void close() {
    super.close();
    linkRuntimeDao = null;
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVer, int newVer) {

}
public Dao<Link, Integer> getLinkDao() throws SQLException {
    if (linkDao == null) {
        linkDao = getDao(Link.class);
    }
    return linkDao;
}
```

Any ideas what's wrong ?

Comment: please post the specific log.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: context argument is null
            at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OpenHelperManager.loadHelper(OpenHelperManager.java:167)
            at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OpenHelperManager.getHelper(OpenHelperManager.java:78)
            at pl.bartos.task.OrmLiteFragment.getHelper(OrmLiteFragment.java:18)
            at pl.bartos.task.Fragments2.onCreate(Fragments2.java:39)

Comment: @Bartos Have you solved the problem?

Comment: @Mark Korzhov yes, I have :)

Comment: @Bartos please post your solution here.

Comment: `databaseHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(getActivity(), DatabaseHelper.class);` you should call this line AFTER the `Activity` has been created. You should use the `Fragment` lifecycle method `onActivityCreated()` to create your `database`.